# when does notifydatasetchanged animates list items separately?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know that notifydatasetchanged updates the whole list and it is recommended to use DiffUtil to only update changed items, what I am not understanding yet after a lot of research is if it's expected that notifydatasetchanged animates list items separately when being used in a RecyclerView. Because I have one RecyclerAdapter where I replace the dataset completely and then call notifyDataSetChanged leading to list items being animated perfectly, **only** those added get the default added animation, removed ones get the removed animation and so on. At the same time I have another adapter where I also do the same, call notifyDataSetChanged but here the whole list flashes shortly, I am not getting any animations automatically, so I don't know from what does notifydatasetchanged make this dependent? Both adapters are too complex and long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2015/02/recyclerview-layoutmanager-3/):

> The framework will attempt to animate views if your adapter uses
>   stable IDs, which provides enough data to guess which views are
>   removed/added/etc